# Mount NAS Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mount, samba, nas

I'm trying to mount a NAS that is on my local network.
[This](https://docs.qnap.com/nas-outdated/QTS4.3.5/en/GUID-445D5C06-7E5A-4232-AC76-CDAF48EDB655.html) website tells me to use

`$ mount <NAS Ethernet Interface IP>:/share/<Shared Folder Name> <Directory to Mount>`

I'm a little unsure what I should provide for `shared folder name` as well as `directory to mount`.

Furthermore [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608044/how-to-mount-a-folder-from-a-nas-drive-in-ubuntu) mentions to first use `$ smbclient -L //<IP>` to see the NAS which in my case gives me `do_connect: Connection to 192.168.178.54 failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)`

Comment: Hello. If you like the answer there is an accept button for you to hit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow it and see if it works!

Comment: which NAS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the shared folder name is the name of the folder on the NAS that you want to have available on the Ubuntu machine.

Like Movies or TV.

The directory to mount to is the directory under mnt that you have created as the mount point. You need to create this directory.

The line about SMB requires you to have installed and setup SMB on the Ubuntu machine assuming your NAS supports SMB.